# "Reading arithmetic coded JPEG files is not implemented"

Tags: adobe-photoshop, file-format

I am unable to open [this JPEG image](https://ak1.ostkcdn.com//images/products/is/images/direct/6f1f5d57a2a292fa762b9822c243e7a74c375551/Dell-Latitude-E5440-Core-i5-4300U-1.9GHz-4th-Gen-CPU-16GB-RAM-240GB-SSD-DVD-RW-Windows-10-Pro-14-inch-Laptop-%28Refurbished%29.jpg) in Photoshop after I download it.

The error message that I get:

[image]
<sub>*Could not complete your request because reading arithmetic coded JPEG files is not implemented.*</sub>

However, Google Chrome seems to be able to display the image just fine:

[image]

After looking for this online, people suggested changing the extension. I tried changing it to a few different ones, but with no success.

How does one open this file in Photoshop?

Comment: For me it opens perfectly OK in Photoshop CC 2018 when I use Firefox to download the image.  But when I try to use Chrome to download the image I get the same error as you when trying to open in Photoshop.  Perhaps this is an issue with Chrome?

Comment: Interesting! I never thought two different browsers could download the same file and produce two different files...

Comment: I don't know if that's actually what's going on.  It could be that Chrome is corrupting the image in some way.  Other windows apps I have simply report that the file is corrupt. Photoshop is the only one that mentions arithmetic coding.

Answer (score 1):

There are actually a few formats that Adobe isn't up to date with.. [webp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebP) is another.

As far as I know if Photoshop won't *open* the file, it won't open the file. Often it takes some small shareware image app that's more quickly updated and supports a particular new file format to open the image and then resave it into a format Adobe products do understand.

Adobe is a behemoth with the speed of one. It can take years before they implement code to support new formats.

And there's always copy/paste which tends to work from a browser window.

Comment: Agreed, although as far as copy/paste goes it might lose items? (EXIF, or as we recently found out, embedded Paths!) - I'll take an answer involving an intermediary app before passing it to PS.

Comment: ...and how about these new up and coming formats like `.cur` and `.ico`, which PS still doesn't natively support :)

Answer (score 1):

Open jpegcrop (which can read JPEG JFIF images arithmetically coded by IJG jpeglib's jaricom.c).

Click File / Preferences to open the Preferences dialog box.

Ensure "Entropy Coding Method" is **not** set to Arithmetic, but instead is set to either "Huffman default" or "Huffman optimized".  Click OK.

Click File / Save Frame As, then save as a typical Huffman encoded .jpg.

---

Besides jpegcrop, any other program built upon the IJG JPEG library (eg, jpegtran) can likely read and/or convert the image -- assuming the library is not excessively old.  My primary experience is with the IJG JPEG v8d (circa 2012).  Any program/app built on a newer IJG JPEG library than that will very likely work to read/convert images arithmetically encoded by IJG jpeglib's jaricom.c.

---

To give you an idea of what standards were used, here's some documentation comments from a circa 2012 version of IJG jpeglib's jaricom.c.  At the beginning:

"This file contains probability estimation tables for common use in
 arithmetic entropy encoding and decoding routines.

This data represents Table D.3 in the JPEG spec (D.2 in the draft),
 ISO/IEC IS 10918-1 and CCITT Recommendation ITU-T T.81, and Table 24
 in the JBIG spec, ISO/IEC IS 11544 and CCITT Recommendation ITU-T T.82."

then at the end:

"This last entry is used for fixed probability estimate of 0.5
 as suggested in Section 10.3 Table 5 of ITU-T Rec. T.851."

Answer (score -1):

- Open the file in Google Chrome.
- Then Control click the image and copy the image.
- Open Photoshop and create a new page from the clipboard and set the resolution you need along with the colour mode.
- Paste the image and save the file to what ever format you need.
- Done